# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead while fitting the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a model on load_hobbies data set from yellowbrick; I wrote the following code to fit the model after I split the data into training and testing datasets.However, i got an error of ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
I don't know why. can anyone help please? Here is the code:

````
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts


#corpus = load_hobbies()
#X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(corpus.data)
#y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(corpus.target)
#
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size=0.2)
#
#model = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
#model.score(X_test, y_test)

corpus = load_hobbies()
X = corpus.data
y = corpus.target
#
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size=0.2)
#
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback

Comment: I guess the problem is with the Label encoder, to transform your data you must pass a matrix to the transformer instead of an array, the method .reshape(-1,1) transforms an array (n_samples,) into a matrix (n_samples,1).

Comment: have you tried reshaping the values?

Answer (score 0):

Though you've imported `TfidfVectorizer` it doesn't appear as though you've used it.

`X = corpus.data` returns a list with all of your document content as strings.  You need to use `TfidfVectorizer` to convert this collection of raw documents to a matrix.

You will also need to turn this sparse matrix into a dense matrix using `X.toarray()`.

Once you do this, you should be able to properly fit your model and visualize using Yellowbrick.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

from yellowbrick.datasets import load_hobbies
from yellowbrick.classifier import ClassificationReport

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts

# Load the data and create document vectors
corpus = load_hobbies()
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()

X = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus.data)
y = corpus.target

# Turn sparse matrix into dense matrix
X = X.toarray()

# Split data into training and testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Instantiate the classification model and visualizer
model = GaussianNB()
visualizer = ClassificationReport(model, support=True)

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)        # Fit the visualizer and the model
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)        # Evaluate the model on the test data
visualizer.show()                       # Finalize and show the figure
```

[image: Yellowbrick Classification Report with Corpus]